# Wrapping JS promises into a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jszip

I have a web application that collects various files from URLs and puts them together in the zip archive.

I'm using [JSZip](http://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_jszip.html) to work with zip files. Here is a code sample that includes contents of another zip archive located on the same server:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   
   <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jszip.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jszip-utils.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/FileSaver.js"></script>

Downloading archive with contents from another archive



<script>

jQuery(function($) {

            var zip = new JSZip();
            zip.file('see.txt','Regular files are being included with a single function call');



            function flash(){
            JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent('/version.zip', function(err, data) {
                try {
                  zip.loadAsync(data)
                  .then(function(zip) {
                        zip.generateAsync({type: 'blob'},
                        function(metadata) {
                        })
                        .then(function(blob) {
                            saveAs(blob, 'result.zip');

                        }, function(e) {
                            showError(e);
                        });
                  })
                  .then(function success() {

                  });
                } catch(e) {console.log(e)}
              });
            };


        flash();



        return false;

});

</script>
```

[Working JSFiddle with libs and examples included](https://jsfiddle.net/6L4zb777/6/)

It works just fine. `JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent` returns a promise with binary content of a zip file from the URL. `zip.loadAsync()` reads binary content and includes it into the archive. `zip.generateAsync` builds a representation of zip archive in RAM so we can download it later.

However, I need to wrap `zip.loadAsync()` into a function that I can call multiple times. I've tried something like this:

```
function zipmerge(source){
JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(source, function (err, data) {
   if(err) {
      throw err; // or handle the error
   }
   var zip = new JSZip();
   zip.loadAsync(data);
});
};
```

But it looks like `zip.loadAsync()` needs a wait in order to be completed. If I just run the function above and then generate a zip file, it will just ignore the contents of zip file I'm trying to incude.

I'm not very good with how promisies work, so I need a help with a function that will recieve an url and wait for the promise to resolve so I could call it multiple times along with regular `zip.file` and then trigger a zip generation. Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what your goal is? Are you trying to read multiple zip files with `loadAsync` and merge them into a single zip?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to make a function "wait" until a promise resolves before it returns.  You can't do that in Javascript.  There is no way to take an async operation and somehow wrap it with a synchronous function that returns the async result. That can't be done. It is asked for often and it can't be done. Instead, you have to learn how to write proper async code where you return a promise from your function and use `.then()` on that promise to know when the async operation is done and then and only then inside that `.then()` handler do you initiate the next step in your sequence.

Comment: @nderscore yes, thats what I'm trying to do. We may assume that we don't know how much archives should be merged / user may add extra archives.

Comment: Also, `throw err` from an async callback will not do anything useful.  The error will likely just be silently eaten and there is no opportunity to `catch` that exception at a higher level because it's thrown from an async callback.  So, basically, never do `throw err` from an async callback.

Comment: Make sure that all your asynchronous function (including the `then` callbacks!) **`return`** a promise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the `JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent` method in a Promise and generate an array of them. Then, you can use `Promise.all()` to create a new promise which resolves when all the promises in an array have resolved.

Here's an example of how I would do it:

```js
// function to read in a list of source zip files and return a merged archive
function mergeZips(sources) {
    var zip = new JSZip();

    return readSources(sources, zip)
        .then(function() {
            return zip;
        });
}

// generate an array of promises for each zip we're reading in and combine them
// into a single promise with Promise.all()
function readSources(files, zip) {
    return Promise.all(
        files.map(function(file){
            return readSource(file, zip);
        })
    );
}

// promise-ified wrapper function to read & load a zip
function readSource(file, zip) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(file, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            // resolving the promise with another promise will pass the promise
            // down the chain:
            resolve(zip.loadAsync(data)); 
        });
    });
}

// example usage:
mergeZips([
    'file1.zip',
    'file2.zip',
    'file3.zip'
]).then(function(zip) {
    zip.generateAsync({type: 'blob'})
        .then(function(blob){
            saveAs(blob, 'result.zip')
        })
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I got the idea. But the code you provied doesn't work, I will try to get what is wrong here.

Comment: @mkrl I was able to fix the code and got it working. I've updated my answer and here's a demo on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ghvw7brt/